# Passing variables in php forms to another page

Tags: php, forum

I am a bit new to PHP and forms. I'm trying to send some variables from one page to another in a PHP form.

This is the form:

```
<form name="dates" action="document_creation/7bform.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return mandatoryFields()">
  <table width="748" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td class="main_text">
        <div align="right" class="main_text">*Contract Start Date:</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="start_date" type="text" value="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="100" class="datepick" id="date1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="main_text">
        <div align="right" class="main_text">*Contract End Date:</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end_date" type="text" value="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="100" class="datepick" id="date2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" colspan="2">
        <table width="100" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
          <tr>
            <td width="68"> <input name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Generate 7B Form" <?php if($disable ==1){?>disabled<?php }?>/></td>
            <td width="48">
              <label><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></label>
            </td>
            <td width="46"><div align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I want to pass `start_date` and `end_date` to another page `document_creation/7bform.php` and it's not working. **document_creation/7bform.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
     $start_date = ($_POST['start_date']);
     $end_date = ($_POST['end_date']);
```

When I try to print these variables, they come out as blank. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: have you tried a print_r($_REQUEST) or print_r($_POST) on the first line of your 7bform.php ? The form looks ok, but not sure whats in your 7bform.php, something in there could be causing problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine, so I think your function `mandatoryFields()` is returning false.

Other than that, you may want to use this on your retrieving page:

```
if(isset($_POST['start_date']) && !empty($_POST['start_date'])){
 // now assign values
}

if(isset($_POST['end_date']) && !empty($_POST['end_date'])){
 // now assign values
}
```

Comment: I removed the  mandatoryFields() function and wrote the code you suggested but when i try to print out the dates for testing, it still doesn't work. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just a helpful tip...

---

```
<?php if($disable ==1){?>disabled<?php }?>
```

---

That is VERY messy... You should use short-tags

---

```
<?=($disable==1 ? " disabled" : "")?>
```

---

And even further, 1 is TRUE, so you don't actually need it...

---

```
<?=($disable ? " disabled" : "")?>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses around your $_POST call. 
Also, you may want to consider sanitizing your strings. I know you're new, but whenever I teach someone PHP forms I always describe sanitary procedures first. 
At @rckhoe, don't use short tags. Short tags are extremely buggy and dependent on browser variables.

You can read about sanitizing your input [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It's always good practice to use `htmlspecialchars()` and using [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) is good too. It also wouldn't hurt to read up more on your PHP/SQL.

```
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
```